# Loading missing columns into Database Diagram design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join many tables from my SQL Server Developer 2017 database. I am trying to see what keys to use for the joins by using the database diagram. Problem is that the dialog box to choose the columns to be diagrammed do not include all tables. How can I import the missing tables into the list? ( Sorry, tried to import screenshot file for 30 minutes)

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about creating a view ? please provide the tables schema (text and not screenshots) and explain which part is missing, and what you've tried so far ? finally, add the expected results. (samples will be really helpful)

Comment: @iSR5: Hi, no, I am trying to create a diagram for a choice of tables. I am working with a large database that requires joining many tables. In order to not have to look up tables separately, I do a diagram of the tables to be joined, to figure out which keys to use.

Comment: yes I've got that you're working with a large database, and trying to simplify some of the tables, however,  we need to see tables schema along with the diagram that you've so far, in order to help you.

Comment: Yes, thanks, for some reason I am having trouble uploading them here. Will keep trying.